# What are "common" (needed/useful to know) SQL Database-operations?

Tags: sql

I am looking for a good list (cheat-sheet?) of SQL tasks/commands for Database operations (although probably all of them are for that).

Stuff like:

- JOIN - merge two tables
- WHERE - subset tables
- And so on

But also a bit more elaborate tasks.

My motivation is that I want to know SQL a bit better, and I thought it would be fun to take a bunch of these tasks and see how to do them with SQL vs how to do them in a language I know (R).

And then maybe put these in a place like this:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Database_operations

(I wasn't able to find this when searching - but if this is a duplicate I'd be happy to close this thread)

Comment: Impossible to answer. The ANSI SQL specification is huge. I don't see any benefit to creating some random list of SQL terms. From the exa,ples you have listed so far you might want to look at the relational algebra operators. or for a good general overview of SQL see Joe Celko "SQL for Smarties"

Answer (score 2):

- `CREATE TABLE`

  - `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL`, and `CHECK` constraints.
  - `DEFAULT`
  - `REFERENCES`
- `DELETE`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `INSERT`
- `REPLACE` (if supported)
- `UPDATE`
- `SELECT`

  - `DISTINCT`
  - `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`
  - `ORDER BY`
  - `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` (if supported)
  - `JOIN` (`INNER` and `OUTER`)
  - `UNION`
- Transactions: `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: `UPDATE` seems to be missing, methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Cheat sheet for joins (Left, Inner, Right, Outer etc) Look at a venn diagram and they basically map i.e. inner join is where the two/three circles all overlap, left is the area in the left circle that doesn't overlap etc.

Comment: Jeff Atwood did a blog post on this. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html. LEFT JOIN would not be as you describe though - at least not without a where clause. That is 'EXCEPT'

Answer (score 1):

You have exactly 4 basic SQL statements:

1. SELECT
2. INSERT
3. UPDATE
4. DELETE

JOIN, WHERE etc are only constituents clauses in one of these 4 statements

A View or stored proc or trigger or functions are simply wrappers for one or more of these 4 statements.